# Read JSON String In C#

Tags: c#, json

Could someone tell me how I would read this JSON string in C#

```
string vitalsString = "{"vitals":{"username":"THCSoftware","balance":"0.00"}}";
```

I need to extract the username and balance values into an array or put them into a listbox if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your code / attempt

Comment: I don't have any attempt as I don't know where to start, I just want to learn JSON as I've never used it before, and a site I use (CodeCanyon) uses JSON in their API and I am attempting to make calls to it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.NET and it allows you to serialize and deserialize JSON objects in C#. Here is the [link](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

After including it in you project you can do it like:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectType>(Object);
```

Comment: Note that `<Type>` is the object type you're trying to convert to, not just "Type" :)

Comment: @intracept: I meant the type of object, I thought the user would understand what I meant but for clarification, I'll make that edit.